# Passing Chrome FileSystem API FileEntry to Web worker

Tags: google-chrome-app, web-worker, fileapi

I'm trying to use a WebWorker to parse certain files from a directory the user selected, like so:

```
function readEntries(reader, callback) {
  reader.readEntries(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(entry) {
      if (entry.isDirectory) { readEntries(entry.createReader(), callback); }
      else { callback(entry); }
    });
  });
}

readEntries(initialDir.createReader(), function(entry) {
  var nodeWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
  nodeWorker.onmessage = function(e) { /* do stuff */ }
  nodeWorker.postMessage(entry);
});
```

The `initialDir` is a `DirectoryEntry` from `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({'type': 'openDirectory'}, ...`.

The corresponding `worker.js` would use `FileReaderSync` to parse the passed file(s) and pass analysis results back to `/* do stuff */`.

If I execute this, I get the following `DOMException`:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': An object could not be cloned.
```

Since `entry.toURL()` returns an empty string, how am I supposed to pass local, unsandboxed files to the web worker? Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What is the variable `results` in the 3rd line of your code?

Comment: @MarcRochkind sorry, that's a typo, it ought to read `results` all the way

Comment: I don't see the entire text of the exception. Can you post it? Also, post what console.log displays for `entry`.

Comment: Try some things:
- Transferring the file in the postMessage (look up Transferables)
- URL.createObjectURL()
- if this "analysis" is something on the content of the files, read the files in your main program then pass them off to the workers to process. Again you can use transferrables.

Comment: Don't you need to include as a second argument to postMessage an array of the transferable objects?